Schengen visa for parents
I am applying for the Schengen visa for my parents. The problem is that my father's surname in his passport does not match the father's name I have in my passport. Could this cause any trouble with his visa application ?

What ‘problem’ do you think it might cause?

The short answer is No.
It is not a stated/written requirement anywhere that you must have your father's name as your surname or other way around. There are many cases when the parents follow different rules and naming conventions. Some surnames are more gender specific especially in some Asian countries and this does not cause any trouble. At least in the case of visa application, there is less focus on the names/surnames and more on the reason of travel, funds available and so on.

I was assuming that OP has a field in his passport that is called "Father's name", and that OP is not referring to his last name as such.

you got it right .I meant my father's name in my passport and the name in his passport does n't match. I am applying my parents visa in category of inviting friends and family. So I think mismatch in the names could cause some issue.
